# Saving Eloquent model with non-nullable polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can save a model with a polymorphic relationship like so:

`$foo->save(); $foo->bars()->save($bar)`

I have a model which has a non-nullable data field, where the data field can be one of many other data types. I cannot first save the model as it expects the data field to be set, so can I save the polymorphic field at the same time as the initial save. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve it by doing it ass-backwards: `$bar->save(); $bar->foo()->save($foo)` or `$child->save(); $child->parent()->save($child);`